# why is z-index not working for opacity?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have two divs, on the outer div I have given an opacity of .1, and then I have an inner div that should not inherit the parent containers opacity property. But to avoid this what I did was to add a z -index property (higher to the child element) but it doesnt work. How do I avoid child div to inherit the opacity property of its parent container:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTMl>
<html>
    <head>  
        <style type="text/css">
            #outer{width:500px;height:400px;background:#000000;border:1px solid red;opacity:.1;z-index:1}
            #inner{width:450px;height:350px;background:#ffffff;margin: 0 auto;margin-top:20px;z-index:2}

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="outer">
            <div id="inner">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't use z-index to position parent/child relative to one another.  A google search for ["opacity inheritance css"](https://www.google.com/webhp?rlz=1C1TSNP_enUS471US471&sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&rlz=1C1TSNP_enUS471US471&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=opacity%20inheritance%20css&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=e90d0913f918c708&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1178&bih=614) gives you a bunch of good articles about your question.

Comment: You may check this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138006/no-opacity-on-div-inside-a-div-with-opacity-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use rgba property to get this working. e-g below should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTMl>
<html>
    <head>  
        <style type="text/css">
            #outer{width:500px;height:400px;background:#000000;border:1px solid red;background:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);}
            #inner{width:450px;height:350px;background:#ffffff;margin: 0 auto;margin-top:20px;background:rgba(255,0,0,1);}

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="outer">
            <div id="inner">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```