# Fix left and right floating images in HTML

Tags: html, css

Here's what I'd like to do: have a banner across the top of a website which stretches all across.  On the left is a menu, and on the right a logo image; the menu floats left, the image floats right.

The problem is the resizing of the browser window.  Because the image floats right, it correctly moves as the window gets smaller.  However, at some point it begins to float into the menu.  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9wNEx/) is a Fiddle that illustrates this effect with two floating images.  Resize the browser window to see how the two images overlap.

Setting

```
body {
  min-width: 800px;
}
```

I can now make sure that the scrollbar appears as the browser window reaches a certain minimum width.  However, that doesn't hinder the right-floating image to keep moving as the browser window keeps getting smaller.  I tried to change `position: relative` but that didn't work.  I tried to use Javascript to fixate the images once the browser window reaches its `min-width` but that didn't seem to have an impact either.  Using `min-width` on the DIV and making the images children of the DIV didn't work either.

My question is: how can I make sure that, starting at a certain window size, the right-floating image stays put instead of floating into the left-floating menu?

EDIT: Oh dear, I forgot to mention a rather important detail: the menu bar at the top needs to be sticky.  That is why I used the `position: fixed` property for the DIV.  The other page content is supposed to scroll under that menu and out of the window, see the modified fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9wNEx/33/) which is based on ntgCleaner's answer.  This kind-of changes the whole thing, doesn't it!  Sorry about that...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things I changed:

1. I made your banner DIV a container instead of just a free floating div.  Probably not necessary.
2. I gave that banner div a min-width:280px and made it overflow:hidden;
3. I made the images just float left and right, not positioned relatively or absolute (since it's in the div container now).

   ```
   #banner {
   left: 0px;
   top: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 60px;
   background-color: lightblue;
   z-index: 1;
   opacity: 0.8;
   overflow:hidden;
   min-width:280px;
   }

   #left {
   float:left;
   margin:5px;
   height:40px;
   }

   #right {
   float:right;
   margin:5px;
   height:40px;
   }
   ```

   ​
   ​

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9wNEx/25/)

EDITED FOR THE EDITED QUESTION:

You will just need to place all of your content under your header into a div, then give that div a top margin of the height of your fixed div.  In this caes, it's 60px.

Add this to your HTML

```
<div id="content">
this <br>
is <br>
some <br>
test <br>
text <br>
</div>
```

then add this to your CSS

```
#content {
    margin:60px 0px 0px 0px;
}​
```

[Here's the new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9wNEx/34/)

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for, but I forgot to mention that the menubar is supposed to be sticky. Please see my EDIT, sorry about that!

Comment: No problem, I believe I have fixed your problem though.  Any div directly below the fixed header must have a top margin the size of the header.

Comment: Ah I see how this works, finally :) Position the image relative to the DIV using its margin instead of left/top values. Then it actually _floats_ correctly. Last question though: since the banner is transparent, so are the images. Setting the IMG `opacity: 1` doesn't seem to have an effect. Is that at all doable?

Comment: To answer my opacity question, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138006/no-opacity-on-div-inside-a-div-with-opacity) is a related answer.

Comment: One more thing: even though the BODY has a `min-width: 800px` the child DIV doesn't seem to inherit that, and I needed to set the `min-width: 800px` for the banner DIV again. Not a problem, just a note.

Comment: Great! I'm glad you have it all fixed up.  I hope the min-width thing works as well.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are after? http://jsfiddle.net/9wNEx/10/

You are not using the `position: fixed` correctly. Fixed means 'positioned relative to the viewport or browser window', and that is exactly what you are experiencing.

I removed the `position: fixed` from the images, and placed them inside the div. This should keep them always on top of the page, as they are inside the div that is still positioned fixed.

Also I tweaked some of the other styling to replicate your example. Note that i removed the fixed height of the head and replaced it by a padding bottom. This way the height will follow the content whenever the screen size becomes to small and the images are forced underneath each other.

The css looks like this now:

```
#banner {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

#left {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 40px;
}

#right {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Please see my EDIT, sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

When I look at your Fiddle I think your problem isn't the floats at all.  `position:fixed` supersedes float.  Those two elements aren't floating at all, they're in a fixed position (similar to an absolute position), which is why they overlap when they don't have enough room.

Take out `float:left` and `float:right`, the result will be the same.  Also, `top`, `left`, `bottom`, and `right` don't work on non-positioned elements.  So they are superfluous on your banner.

If you use floats, however, when there is not enough room the right image will wrap underneath the left.  See http://codepen.io/morewry/pen/rjCGd.  Assuming the heights on the images were set for jsfiddle testing only, all you need is:

```
.banner {
    padding: 5px; /* don't repeat padding unnecessarily */
    min-width: ??; /* to keep floats from wrapping, set one */
    overflow: hidden; /* clearfix */
}

.right { float: right; } /* only need one float, don't over-complicate it with two */
```

Comment: Please see my EDIT, sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

I changed your HTML to put the `<img>` tags inside the banner, and added the min-width to the `#banner` since it has `position: fixed`. You'll still need to add `min-width` to the `body` or a container that wraps all other elements if you want there to be a min-width of the entire page.

http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/s8bQL/

```
<div id="banner">
    <img id="left" src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" />
    <img id="right" src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" />
</div>
```

```
#banner {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 800px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 0.8; }

#left {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 0 0 10px;
    height: 40px; }
#right {
    float: right;
    margin: 5px 10px 0 0;
    height: 40px; }
```

​

Comment: Thank you, Wex! It's getting closer to what I'm looking for. The ideal solution would be ntgCleaner's approach with a sticky menu bar: as the window resizes to a smaller width, a scroll bar appears. I can't figure out how to prevent the images from wrapping. I think the issue is somehow related to the `float: right` as this renders the image relative to the right border, and that border keeps moving as the browser window resizes...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The images don't wrap in my version.

Comment: When I resize the browser window and the "Result" pane becomes very narrow, then the two images wrap, i.e. the left one stays where it is and the right one moves below the left one.